# Node.js: express + promise-mysql returns

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, promise

I'm using promise-mysql with express.js, and I want to know if there is any way to get a single object by using the function `con.query(...)`, because it returns an array with one element.

for emaple:

```
// get one by id
const getById = async (id) => {
    const con = await dbConnection();
    const getByIdQuery = await qr('account/get-by-id.sql');

    try {
        return await con.query(getByIdQuery, [id]);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you could do:

```
// get one by id
const getById = async (id) => {
    const con = await dbConnection();
    const getByIdQuery = await qr('account/get-by-id.sql');

    try {
        const [result] = await con.query(getByIdQuery, [id]);
        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    }
};
```